# Change type of promise returned by async functions to a different type

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, parse-server

Edit - While the answers contain a couple of viable solutions, I'll point out that Parse JS SDK 2.0 (and thus Parse-Server 3.0) have been announced, and actually remove Parse.Promise. So, the best solution would be to swap out Parse Promise implementations and use native Promises instead.

I use Parse-Server ( latest version, 2.8.2 ) as a backend.  I got very used to promises, and they are heavily ingrained in my code.

I've been starting to use the async / await pattern instead, though. But it isn't playing nicely with all of my existing implementations.

This example will throw an error:

```
const promiseErrorTestHelper = async () => {
    return Parse.Promise.as();
}

Parse.Cloud.define('promiseErrorTest', async(req, res) => {
    promiseErrorTestHelper().always(
        res.success
    );
});
```

This one works fine:

```
const promiseErrorTestHelper = async () => {
    return Parse.Promise.as();
}

Parse.Cloud.define('promiseErrorTest', async(req, res) => {
    promiseErrorTestHelper().then(
        res.success
    );
});
```

In Parse-Server, `.always()` is used to pass a callback function whether the promise was rejected or resolved. I have used this throughout my code, and discovered the issue while refactoring some functions to use async / await while adding new functionality.

I understand the issue to be that async functions wrap their result in a promise. So, it's taking my `Parse.Promise` and converting it to a different type that does not have the `.always()` method.

Is there by chance a simple way for me to override the functionality of async to return a Parse.Promise instead? Or will I have to rework the `always()` calls if I want to use async / await?

Comment: Maybe add a `.always()` method to the built-in promise which is returned by an `async` function.  `Promise.prototype.always = function(fn) {...}`.

Comment: Also, it's unusual for a lot of your processing to be exactly the same whether the promise resolves or rejects.  So, that makes me think maybe you aren't using resolve and reject properly if you're always using `.always()`.

Comment: It does not look like there's any way to change the type of promise that an `async` function returns.  That is hard-wired into Javascript.  You can wrap the native promise returned from your `async` function with a wrapper that converts it to another type of promise, but that adds code to every `await` that you want to do that with.

Comment: FYI, here's a similar discussion about folks trying to get `async` functions to return promises from the Bluebird promise library: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1434.  Conclusion - can't do it without wrapping the returned promise in another promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks a lot for doing some research! What you first mentioned is what I was hoping I'd be able to do, shame I can't get a hold of what gets returned by async. It's not core functionality that we do this `always` stuff with. It's for say, sending us alert messages about activity or pinging our event server to track an event. After all of the database updates have gone through, I don't want to halt a function because my event ping somehow failed. I know that's not the ideal solution, but it was quick for us. It's just not compatible with async/await.

Comment: To continue after an error, the usual way is to just use a `.catch()` that logs the error and doesn't rethrow.  That will "handle" the error and change the promise chain to resolved.  A following `.then()` can then continue processing.

Comment: I don't do this in a ton of places, but I had reworked one function working its way to callback / promise hell, and it was one that used .always() in a lot of the places it was called. So, all of a sudden I got a bunch of errors where I had been explicitly trying to ignore them. My quick solution, since my rework had a bit of functionality update I wanted to save, and didn't want to go through and rework the `.always()` calls, was to wrap the helper function in its own async helper function, with the original helper function itself returning a `Parse.Promise` like it used to.

Comment: Yeah the .catch was the other solution I found, but I didn't like how I had to update it in a bunch of places when the problem was originating from one point. 

To be clear, I don't write new code with this `.always()` stuff, this is just an issue with legacy code. I had been trying to rework as I learned new practices and updated some old functions, and every now and again stumble across something unexpectedly not compatible, like this. All of my async functions have a try / catch first thing, so the cases I'd use `.always()` I often just call the function without await. Is that bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you cannot change what type of promise is returned from an `async` function.  It is built-in to return a native promise and is not configurable.  There's a similar discussion here about how to make an `async` function return a Bluebird promise [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1434).  The conclusion was that you can't so if you want a Bluebird promise, you have to wrap the `async` function.

---

To continue after an error, the usual way is to use a `.catch()` that logs the error and doesn't rethrow, thus "handling" the error:

```
someFunc().catch(err => {
    // handle the error, continue processing, changes promise chain to resolved
    console.log(err);
    return null;
}).then(() => {
    // will always get called when original promise resolves or rejects
    // somewhat like your .always
});
```

Or, you can wrap your async functions to return your desired type of promise:

```
function wrapFunc(arg) {
    return Parse.Promise.resolve(someAsyncFunc(arg))
}
```

And, then call the wrapper function instead.

---

I'm not sure I recommend this because you are modifying the globally accessible Promise prototype which could affect other code, but you could also add a `.always()` to the built-in promise.

```
Promise.prototype.always = function(fn) {
    return this.then(fn, fn);
}
```

Which is actually the exact same implementation [that Parse uses](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/src/ParsePromise.js#L198).  Then, you can use `.always()` on promises returned from `async` functions.

Comment: I added a couple new options to my answer.  One for wrapping your async function in a new function that returns a Parse promise and the other for adding `.always()` to the native promise that an `async` function returns.

Comment: Oh I like the new example! That looks like the quick solution I was looking for. I'm wondering, how 'dangerous' would this be? Wouldn't anything currently trying to access `.always()` crash anyway right now? I can't think of a case it would be getting called if it didn't exist before, and even if so, can't really think of why it would be doing anything more than exactly what's going on here.

Comment: @JakeT. - It's just the usual issue with modifying a global object.  If more than one library tries to modify it and they try to do it in incompatible ways, you get conflicts between different libraries used in the same project.  You can do it safely if you know nothing else you are using is also trying to do this.  That can be managed for a smaller project, much harder to do with a larger project with lots of people working on it.

Comment: Didn't take long for this question to become a bit moot, Parse JS SDK 2.0 is coming out soon and removes the Parse.Promise in favor of the native promise. So I guess my real answer is to remove any calls to `always`....

Answer (score 0):

jfriend00's answer is an acceptable solution. `.catch(value => {return value}).then(...)` will basically function as an `.always()`.

In my case, I didn't want to do that because it meant I was patching code in many places to fix an issue originating in one. I was reworking an existing function that used `Parse.Promise`s to use async / await, and I had added a little bit of functionality to it, too. I didn't discover the `.always()` issue until I was done. I didn't want to simply throw out the rework and redo the update again with promises.

While sloppy, I ended up wrapping my helper function in a helper function of its own. The original helper function is *not* async and returns a promise resolved based on the result of the async helper-helper function.

```
const promiseErrorTestHelper = async (<same params>) => {
    let returnPromise = new Parse.Promise();

    promiseErrorTestHelperHelper(<same params>).then(
        success => { returnPromise.resolve(success); },
        error => { returnPromise.reject(error); }
    );

    return returnPromise;
}

const promiseErrorTestHelperHelper = async () => {
    // This can return whatever, body and parameters
    // copied in entirety from parent function
}

Parse.Cloud.define('promiseErrorTest', async(req, res) => {
    promiseErrorTestHelper().then(
        res.success
    );
});
```

This enabled me to call the original helper function the same way I had been previously, though the implementation was updated to be much cleaner and more readable.

One thing, though, is that I couldn't use functional programming, which I've been learning about recently and trying to put in practice. This did NOT work:

```
const promiseErrorTestHelper = async (<same params>) => {
    let returnPromise = new Parse.Promise();

    promiseErrorTestHelperHelper(<same params>).then(
        returnPromise.resolve,
        returnPromise.reject
    );

    return returnPromise;
}
```

My understanding is that this should have been virtually the same as the above, just without being wrapped in an anonymous function. Sure, the variable isn't named, but should be passed into those methods either way, right? I use this pattern elsewhere, though not for promise.resolve / reject as I'd just return that directly. But I have plenty of `.then( response.success, response.error )` calls for my cloud functions, rather than doing what I have in the working example above with `returnPromise.resolve` swapped with `response.success` and `returnPromise.reject` swapped with `response.error`. Those work fine.

Comment: Did you see the options I added to my answer?  FYI, your wrapping can be done a lot more succinctly (see the wrap solution in my answer).

Comment: I did, right after I posted mine. I did think to wrap my promise like that, but when I started using this method I intentionally had it still *return* errors, and used `.always()` when I used it when I didn't want it failing to be a fail case. I figured the function doesn't need to know that i intend to ignore the error in most cases, it should just "do it's job" (although I probably should have used a more succinct job).  There are a couple spots where I do call this function and fail on it. I.e. some of my cloud functions where the event log is the only indication an event happened.

Comment: I'm not saying I'm doing it the best way. I just wanted to match the previous functionality as much as possible. Do you have any idea why I might have had to create the anonymous functions instead of being able to pass `returnPromise.resolve/reject` into the `.then()`? It also failed when I just tried `return promiseErrorTestHelperHelper.then(...);`, though now that I think about it, I was trying to pass the function instead of doing the callback, so maybe it was just that and I didn't have to explicitly return a promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 and hey I really appreciate the time, and multiple answers. More than I could have hoped for.